# Comparing string word by word in C

Tags: c, string

Here's a program:
At first, user inputs a text string (`char text1;`);
Then I separate the string in words by copying each word in an array (`char words[20][200]`);

**I want to** compare the string word by word and duplicate each word that doensn't repeat in the `text1` string. Words that are repeating in `text1` will be copied "as is" in the new string (`char text2`).

**Example 1:**
If User inputs "`hello world`"
 then Result must be "`hello hello world world`"

**Example 2:**
If User inputs "`weather is good weather`"
 then Result must be "`weather is is good good weather`"

**The problem is** that if I input "`hello world`" then in result I get "`hello hello world`".

How could I solve this?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char text1[200], text2[200], words[20][100], *dist;
    int i, j, nwords=0;

// Text input
    printf("\n Enter the text:  ");
    gets(text1);


// Separate text word by word   
    dist = strtok(text1, " ,.!?");
    i=0;
    while(dist!=0)
    {      
        strcpy(words[i],dist);
        dist = strtok(NULL, " ,.!?");
        i++;
        nwords++;                
    }

// Task    
    if(nwords=1)
    {
        strcat(text2,words[0]);
        strcat(text2," ");
        strcat(text2,words[0]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<nwords-1; i++)
        for(j=i+1; j<nwords; j++)
        {

        if(strcmp(words[i],words[j])==0)
        {
            strcat(text2,words[i]);                                
        }
        else
        {
            strcat(text2,words[i]);
            strcat(text2," ");
            strcat(text2,words[i]);
        }                                             
    }

// Result
    printf("\n\nInput:\n");
    puts(text1);
    printf("\n\nResult:\n");
    puts(text2);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `nvardi` ? You mean nwords.

Comment: Yes, sorry for my mistake. There should have been "nwords".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question description your program logic is not correct.

> I want to compare the string word by word and duplicate each word that
>   doensn't repeat in the text1 string. Words that are repeating in text1
>   will be copied "as is" in the new string (char text2).

If you take an example of "hello world" string and your code as below

```
for(i=0; i<=nvardi-1; i++)
        for(j=i+1; j<nvardi; j++)
        {

        if(strcmp(vardi[i],vardi[j])==0)
        {
            strcat(text2,vardi[i]);                                
        }
        else
        {
            strcat(text2,vardi[i]);
            strcat(text2," ");
            strcat(text2,vardi[i]);
        }                                             
    }
```

when inner loop will run for "world" string, it is looking at end of the string.

To make it correct, follow following steps -

1. calculate number of similar words in the string, and store it an array.
2. if number of words are more than once copy once only.

it would look like this -

```
int flag_arr[20];
memset(flag_arr, 0, 20);
for(i=0; i <= nwords-1; i++) {
for(j=0; j<=nwords-1; j++)
{
    if(strcmp(words[i],words[j])==0)
    {
        flag_arr[i] += 1;
    }
    }
}
for(i = 0; i <=nwords-1; i++)
{
    if(flag_arr[i] > 1)
    {
        strcat(text2,words[i]);                              
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(text2,words[i]);
        strcat(text2," ");
        strcat(text2,words[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: So you mean - 

1. I need to calculate how many times each word repeats in the string;

2. If current word repeats more than once then copy it in text2 only once, but if it doesn't repeat then duplicate it in the text2 string.


Did I got it right?

Comment: Thanks, it almost did the trick. But there is a problem - if I enter "weather is good weather" then the result is "weather is is good good weather weather". But in this case there at the end of the string word "weather" shouldn't be duplicated. How could I fix this?

Comment: my bad. we need to match in forward and backward both order, i am storing value of number of matched words and if it is more than once then copying only once. see the edited code.

Answer (score 0):

1. You use strtok(3) incorrectly. It accepts delimiter as second string, not a "set" of delimeters.
2. From gets(3):

   Never use gets().

Comment: Um.. The second argument to `strtok()` is a terminated *string* of characters, *each* of which is considered an allowable delimiter. [See the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad. Time to sleep.